# Condensing duplicate data while maintaining multiple entries per client

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I apologize if the title is not descriptive enough. I am having a hard time describing what I am looking for.

I understand this is normally done on the front end but a client is requesting to have this data displayed in this way. this should show a single column with client information (lastname, firstname) and any/all booked appointments. Since there may be more than one appointment per client duplicate data will be displayed along each line. That will look like this:

### lastName  |  firstName  |  apptDate  |  myStartTime  |  myEndTime

smith..............| john................| 4/7/2016........| 7:00.........................| 8:00

smith..............| john................| 4/9/2016........| 6:00.........................| 7:00

smith..............| john................| 4/14/2016......| 10:00.......................| 11:00

arnold.............| williams..........| 4/10/2016......| 7:00.........................| 11:00

arnold.............| williams..........| 4/11/2016......| 8:00.........................| 12:00

but I would like that to be displayed as:

smith..............| john................| 4/7/2016........| 7:00.........................| 8:00

................................................| 4/9/2016........| 6:00.........................| 7:00

................................................| 4/14/2016......| 10:00.......................| 11:00

arnold..............| williams.........| 4/10/2016.......| 7:00.........................| 11:00

................................................| 4/11/2016.......| 8:00.........................| 12:00

This is what I am currently working with:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.clientID    
    END                                                       AS 'clientID' 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.lastName 
    END                                                       AS 'lastName'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.firstName 
    END                                                       AS 'firstName'
    ,CASE
        WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.homePhone                
    END                                                       AS 'home'
    ,CASE
        WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.cellPhone                
    END                                                       AS 'cell'
    ,info.*
    ,CASE
        WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.staffAlertMsg            
    END                                                       AS 'alert'   
    ,cli.notes                                                AS 'notes' 
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10),cli.classDate,101)                   AS 'date'
    ,cli.myStartTime                                          AS 'start'
    ,cli.myEndTime                                            AS 'end'
    ,cli.typeName                                             AS 'appointment'
FROM 
(SELECT
    c.clientID
    ,c.lastName
    ,c.firstName
    ,c.homePhone
    ,c.cellPhone
    ,info.*
    ,r.notes
    ,c.staffAlertMsg  
    ,r.ClassDate
    ,r.myStartTime
    ,r.myEndTime
    ,vt.TypeName
    ,ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY c.clientID ORDER BY c.clientID) AS 'rownum'
FROM clients c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReservation r
        ON c.clientID = r.clientID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVisitTypes vt
        ON vt.TypeID = r.visitType
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT
            max(CASE
                WHEN civ.clientIndexID = 4 
                    THEN civ.clientIndexValueName
            END)                                 AS 'priority'
            ,max(CASE
                WHEN civ.clientIndexID = 5 
                    THEN civ.clientIndexValueName
            END)                                 AS 'lang'
            ,max(CASE
                WHEN civ.clientIndexID = 17 
                    THEN civ.clientIndexValueName
            END)                                 AS 'inter'
            ,max(CASE
                WHEN ccf.name LIKE 'prac'
                    THEN ccv.TextVal
            END)                                 AS 'prac'
            ,max(CASE
                WHEN st.TypeID = 100000001 THEN st.typeName
            END)                                 AS 'ride?'
            ,max(CASE
                WHEN st.typeID = 100000006 THEN st.typeName
            END)                                 AS 'l?'
            FROM tblClientCustomValues ccv
                INNER JOIN tblClientCustomFields ccf
                    ON ccv.ID = ccf.ID
                INNER JOIN tblClientIndexData cid
                    ON ccv.clientID = cid.clientID
                INNER JOIN tblClientIndexValue civ
                    ON cid.clientIndexValueID = civ.clientIndexValueID
                LEFT JOIN [type details] td
                    ON ccv.clientID = td.clientID
                LEFT JOIN [student types] st
                    ON td.typeID = st.typeID
         WHERE c.clientID = ccv.clientID
    ) info
) cli

WHERE cli.clientID != '-2' 
    AND cli.clientID != '0' 
    AND cli.clientID != '1' 
    AND (cli.classDate >= '4/1/2016' 
    AND cli.classDate <= '4/30/2016')
```

Comment: How will the client view the data?  Are you trying to write a script they will run directly against the db?  Will you always pivot a set number of rows into columns?  Is there a maximum number of appointments?

Comment: This data will be generated weekly and exported to excel. I have advised their administrator they could simply remove the duplicate entries once in Excel. Just want to cover all of my options. Each client may have anywhere from 1-20+ Appointments - it varies (which is where the real issue is). There is no maximum.

Comment: One option is to use [Excel's conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) to hide duplicated names (as white text on a white background, for example).

Comment: destination-data -- this is what I was thinking as well. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to only return the name for the first row of each client then this should work (also assuming a primary key column of `ID` on the `clients` table):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.lastName END AS lastName
,CASE WHEN cli.rownum = 1 THEN cli.firstName END AS firstName
,CONVERT(varchar(10),cli.apptDate,101) AS 'apptDate'
,cli.myStartTime
,cli.myEndTime

FROM 

(SELECT c.ID
    ,c.lastName
    ,c.firstName
    ,r.apptDate
    ,r.myStartTime
    ,r.myEndTime
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY c.ID, r.apptDate, r.myStartTime) as rownum

    FROM clients c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReservation r
    ON c.clientID = r.clientID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVisitTypes vt
    ON vt.TypeID = r.VisitType) 
cli

ORDER BY cli.ID, cli.rownum
```

I have made both the join `LEFT OUTER JOINS` as your second `INNER JOIN` would have made the first join an `INNER`, which I assume is not what you wanted.

Comment: You are correct. left that one out. Thanks for the catch. I am going to test this against my db shortly. Thanks for helping out! :)

Comment: You'll probably want some ordering to ensure that the appointments and null rows appear correctly so I've added that in too.

Comment: strickt01 -- thank you! This is looking perfect. What if I were to include an outer apply to avoid duplicate information (I do have a lot of extra information to be included). Should the OUTER APPLY be included within cli?

Comment: Within `cli` I would have thought (but without knowing the schema it is impossible to be sure). If you are using the `OUTER APPLY` to avoid duplication then the `row_number` value should not be affected.Thus if you need the `rownum` to be able to nullify columns brought back from the `OUTER APPLY` in your final `SELECT` then it needs to be in `cli`.

Comment: strickt01 -- I've updated the query above with what I'm currently working with. i'm having trouble in the first SELECT statement ---> info.*

Not able to pull the data from the outer apply when its in cli. I'm most likely referencing it incorrectly ---> "Error in query: The column prefix 'info' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query."

Comment: `info` is within the `cli` nested `SELECT` and is thus not something you can reference in the outer `SELECT`. You need to use `cli.Priority`, `cli.lang`, `cli.inter` etc.

Comment: strickt01 -- OK. That clears that part up. When I run it the first row doesn't include name but starts with blank name and a load of visits (date/times). Working to clear this up now but no luck so far.

Comment: You haven't added in the ordering that I put in within the `OVER` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER` AND at the end of the query. The `ORDER BY` at the end of the main `SELECT` and within the `ROW_NUMBER` column need to mirror each other (as per my example above).

Comment: strickt01 -- THANK YOU! I did overlook that part and my WHERE was in the wrong spot, too. Perfection.